# Why React behave differently in both cases?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am facing a strange behavior in my react app, may be i am not fully understand how react works yet!

**App.js**

```
import CertianPage from './certainPage.js';

const App = ({statePiece}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
     fetchData() // this will fetch data and set it to statePiece 
  }, [])
  console.log(statePiece);

  return (
     <CertainPage />
  )
}

const mapSateToProps = state => ({
   statePiece: state.statePiece
})
```

**certainPage.js**:

```
const CertainPage = ({statePiece}) => {
  console.log(statePiece)
  return (
   
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
   statePiece: state.statePiece 
}
```

Now when i navigate to CertainPage page, this what is logged in my console:

```
{} // the initial state of statePiece -------> App.js
{data} // after fetching  data in App.js ----- App.js
{data} // in CertainPage -------> certainPage.js
```

But when an error happens in `CertainPage` component this what i get in the console?

```
{} //App.js and i get nothing from CertianPage component
// error logged here
```

In the first situation, it seems that the initial state logged before data reach and i think react waited for data reach before calling `CertainPage` component

But this doesn't happen in the second situation, first the initial state logged then the error happened in `CertainPage` component and this prevented logging the data fetched in App.js.

I expected this would happen instead:

```
{} // first logging the inital state
{data} // then logging data after fetch
// then console will show errors here
```

**Why React behave differently in both cases??**

Comment: mapStateToProps subscribes your component to Redux store updates. Store is updated, mapStateToProps is called. It looks like that's happening here, as your initial state is being updated. Why would you expect that to happen before the error?

Comment: As far as I know, `useEffect()` hook is triggered *after* the component is rendered; if your "CertainPage" component throws an error, the `useEffect()` hook code will not be executed therefore you will not fetch the data and update the store.

Comment: ok but why in the first situation, when no errors in ```CertainPage``` component, why not an empty object logged from ```certainComponent``` before data fetch??

Comment: @JakeWorth i understand this part, but this doesn't apply to first situation, why i never get an empty object from CertainPage component before data get fetched?

Comment: @CodeEagle I'd like to help more, but when I run code like this in CodeSandbox, I get a SyntaxError "Unexpected token" on the empty parens in `CertainPage`. I would fix that error, and then try to make sense of the output.

Comment: @JakeWorth I am really sorry for your time, but i found the problem. i get confused by two files named the same called index.js, the output is right, i got an empty object from the page i thought the log come from index.js file in the root directory, really sorry its me:(

Comment: @JakeWorth any way you can add you first comment as an answer if you want and i will be here to accept, thank you!

Comment: No problem @CodeEagle! I'm not sure I answered the question. A tip for logging is to add a string, such as `console.log("state from App.js ", state)`. It's too easy to make an incorrect assumption and go down the wrong path :).

Comment: @JakeWorth yes you are right, that will save much time debugging

Comment: @JakeWorth, that is strange because, as you can see from this snippet I quickly put together, you **should** see the empty object logged by `CertainPage`: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-snippet-vy3p5

Comment: @secan your Code Sandbox throws an error; the OP returns an empty parens from `CertainPage`, which is a SyntaxError.

Comment: @JakeWorth, sorry I meant to mention the OP in my previous comment and I got confused with the names. The aim of the snippet I linked is just to demonstrate that, if no error occurs, the code *does* log the initial state from both components and not just from `App`; I was answering to the OP question "why is not an empty object logged from `certainComponent` before data fetch??". Apologies for the confusion I caused.

Comment: @secan, Thanks, but i couldn't understand this part, this is strange to me somwhow ```const App = connect(appStateToProps)(({ dataProp }) => {```

can you explain please?

Comment: Well, if you want to use Redux in order to map the state to e component props you need to use the `connect()` function. Usually you would use it in the export statement (`export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)`) but my snippet is all on a single file therefore I had to use it in this alternative way.